# Issue with bound service on orientation changed

Tags: android, service, screen-orientation

My app have its informations stored on its service and in onCreate() binds to it to verify what is the service state to load the informations. I though it would made change orientation easy cause they will recover his state from service on recreate. But my problem is that when onDestroy is called, it calls unbindService, but the onCreate is called before onServiceDisconnect, what cause some problems. Here are some of my methods:

On Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    MyService.log("Activity onCreate()");

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);

    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    drawerlayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawerlayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, Gravity.LEFT);

    // activity sendo criada pela primeira vez e não por mudança de
    // orientação

    registerReceivers();
    // cancelaNotificacao(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    Intent it = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    if (!MyService.RUNNING) {
        startService(it);
    }

    if (!bindService(it, this, 0)) {
        mensagemErro("Erro!",
                "Não foi possível conectar ao service. Fechando app.");
        finish();
    }

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceivers();
    unbindService(this);

}

@Override
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder binderservice) {
    MyService.log("Activity onServiceConnected");
    LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) binderservice;
    this.service = binder.getService();

    carregaRadio();

    if (MyService.bot != null && MyService.bot.isConnected()) {
        carregaChatdoService();
        selectTab(TITLE_TAB_CHAT);
    } else {
        carregaLogin();
        selectTab(TITLE_TAB_RADIO);
    }

}

@Override
public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
    service = null;
}
```

On Service:

```
public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    public MyService getService() {
        // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public
        // methods
        return MyService.this;
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    log("Service Bind.");

    BOUND = true;
    return mBinder;

}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    log("Service Unbind.");

    BOUND = false;
    boolean stopserviceflag = true;

    // Se nem o bot do irc e nem o player estao ativos, o service pode parar
    // tambem
    if (bot != null && bot.isConnected()) {
        stopserviceflag = false;
    }

    if (playerStarted) {
        stopserviceflag = false;
    }

    if (stopserviceflag) {
        log("Service Stop.");
        stopSelf();
    }

    return super.onUnbind(intent);
}
```

I guess if my onServiceDisconnected would called before onCreate it would work, but sincerely dont know.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the service in `Activity` `onStart` and `unbind the service` in `onStop` . This will fix you issues in orientation change.

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Bind to LocalService
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourService.class);
    bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    // Unbind from the service if already bound . 
    // mBound will be true if service connection is established when onServiceConnected is called
    if (mBound) {
        unbindService(mConnection);
        mBound = false;
    }
}
```

This will make sure that the `service` is `bound` with `Activity`  only when the `Activity` is in foreground(visible and interactive to user).

Comment: onCreate still being called just after onDestroy() and before onServiceDisconnected. On Debug i see that onUnbind() method of service is called only after onStart(), what confuses everything...

Comment: Happy to have developed the first application in the world not compatible with landscape orientation :)